# Query a boolean property in NDB Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a Greeting model

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
    avatar = ndb.BlobProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    public = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

wherein I use the following code to query seven Greeting posts at each page in Python Google App Engine:

```
posts_query = Greeting.query(
ancestor=session_key(session_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
curs = Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('cursor'))
posts,next_curs, more = posts_query.fetch_page(7, start_cursor=curs)
```

I wanted it to show only posts to that has public modified into True so I changed it into

```
posts_query = Greeting.query(
ancestor=session_key(session_name), Greeting.public == True).order(-Greeting.date) #line changed
curs = Cursor(urlsafe=self.request.get('cursor'))
posts,next_curs, more = posts_query.fetch_page(7, start_cursor=curs)
```

However, it is giving me an error:

```
File "/home/ralf/Desktop/google_projects/website/views/events.py", line 28
    Greeting.public == True).order(-Greeting.date)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

How can I fix this? What is the appropriate code for this kind of query? Help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. As you can see I am also using a query cursor.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is necessarily related to App Engine. Python does not allow non keyword arguments (positional) after keyword arguments. You have a positional argument "Greeting.content == "test8"", after a keyword argument "ancestor=session_key(session_name)", so it is not valid python.

Comment: @dyeray Sorry, I'm going to edit my question. That is not the error line that is now showing.

Comment: @dyeray There it's now updated. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this

```
posts_query = Greeting.query(Greeting.public == True).order(-Greeting.date)
```

instead of

```
posts_query = Greeting.query(ancestor=session_key(session_name),
        Greeting.public == True).order(-Greeting.date)
```

Yes, reversing the order of `ancestor=session_key(session_name)` and `Greeting.public == True` in the query function removes the errors. However, I found that my answer is a good fix considering that it is a part of a feature I added in my website.

`ancestor=session_key(session_name)` is not needed at all for public users of the app. They just view the page and does not login at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had some complicated query with positional and non-positional arguments and it was getting confusing, you can also split it into two lines:

```
posts_query = Greeting.query(ancestor=session_key(session_name))
posts_query = posts_query.filter(Greeting.public == True)
```

This 'filter building' can be repeated as many times as necessary.